# In sklearn, it seems that `dot(x, x)` corresponds to `np.sum(X*X,axis=1)[:, np.newaxis]`, why is that?

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn

In a 2d Euclidean space,

Let point $a=(a_x, a_y)=(1,1)$;

Let point $b=(b_x, b_y)=(5,1)$;

Let point $c=(c_x, c_y)=(4,4)$;

the squared Euclidean distance between point a and point b is equal to

$(a_x-b_x)^2 + (a_y - b_y)^2$.

```
>>> a = np.array([1,1])
>>> b = np.array([5,1])
>>> np.linalg.norm(a-b)**2
16.0
```

the squared Euclidean distance between point a and point c is equal to

$(a_x-c_x)^2 + (a_y - c_y)^2$

```
>>> a = np.array([1,1])
>>> c = np.array([4,4])
>>> np.linalg.norm(a-c)**2
18.0
```

[sklearn.metrics.pairwise.euclidean_distances](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.euclidean_distances.html) uses this approach to compute the distances

```
>>> X = np.array([[1,1]])
>>> Y = np.array([[5,1],[4,4]])
>>> np.sum(X*X,axis=1)[:, np.newaxis] - 2*np.dot(X,Y.T) + np.sum(Y*Y,axis=1)[np.newaxis, :]
array([[16, 18]])
```

which corresponds to this formula

> dist(x, y) = sqrt(dot(x, x) - 2 * dot(x, y) + dot(y, y))

it seems that `dot(x, x)` corresponds to `np.sum(X*X,axis=1)[:, np.newaxis]`, why is that?

Comment: Are you questioning $<x,x>=\sum x_i^2$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dot(x, x)` means the dot product of two vectors

${\displaystyle \mathbf {\color {red}a} \cdot \mathbf {\color {blue}b} =\sum _{i=1}^{n}{\color {red}a}_{i}{\color {blue}b}_{i}={\color {red}a}_{1}{\color {blue}b}_{1}+{\color {red}a}_{2}{\color {blue}b}_{2}+\cdots +{\color {red}a}_{n}{\color {blue}b}_{n}}$

plug in x

dot(x, x) = ${\displaystyle \mathbf {\color {red}x} \cdot \mathbf {\color {blue}x}} = x_1x_1+x_2x_2=x_1^2+x_2^2$

Vectorizing this computation gets `np.sum(x*x)` in Python

more info at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product