# Why the dot product of two vectors in sklearn is not a scalar?

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn

In a 2d Euclidean space,

Let point $a=(a_x, a_y)=(1,1)$;

Let point $b=(b_x, b_y)=(5,1)$;

Let point $c=(c_x, c_y)=(4,4)$;

the squared Euclidean distance between point a and point b is equal to

$(a_x-b_x)^2 + (a_y - b_y)^2$.

```
>>> a = np.array([1,1])
>>> b = np.array([5,1])
>>> np.linalg.norm(a-b)**2
16.0
```

the squared Euclidean distance between point a and point c is equal to

$(a_x-c_x)^2 + (a_y - c_y)^2$

```
>>> a = np.array([1,1])
>>> c = np.array([4,4])
>>> np.linalg.norm(a-c)**2
18.0
```

[sklearn.metrics.pairwise.euclidean_distances](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.euclidean_distances.html) uses this approach to compute the distances

```
>>> X = np.array([[1,1]])
>>> Y = np.array([[5,1],[4,4]])
>>> np.sum(X*X,axis=1)[:, np.newaxis] - 2*np.dot(X,Y.T) + np.sum(Y*Y,axis=1)[np.newaxis, :]
array([[16, 18]])
```

which corresponds to this formula

> dist(x, y) = sqrt(dot(x, x) - 2 * dot(x, y) + dot(y, y))

per this [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/423603/257182)

`dot(x, x)` in the formula above means the dot product of two vectors.

per [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product)

the dot product of two vectors

> is a scalar, rather than a vector

but the result of this Python code

```
>>> X = np.array([[1,1]])
>>> np.sum(X*X,axis=1)
array([2])
```

is an array (represents a vector) rather than a scalar, why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one could represents an array

```
a = np.array([1,1])
```

and `X` is a matrix rather than an array.

```
X = np.array([[1,1]])
```

Both this line of code

```
np.sum(a*a)
```

and this one

```
np.dot(a,a)
```

could get the dot product of two vectors (actually a vector and itself in this case)

```
2
```

which is

> a scalar, rather than a vector